# Python Flask - Error: "Failed to load module script. Strict MIME type checking is enforced". Works on production, not on the local server

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, http-headers

I have this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="../../../static/css/style.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="../../../static/css/user_header.css"
        type="text/css" />

    <!--suppress HtmlUnknownTarget -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png">

    <script type="module" src="../../../static/js/node_connect.js" ></script>  <-- Error
    <script src="../../../static/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../static/lib/selfserve.js"></script>   

</head>
```

The problematic bit is the `node_connect.js` file. When starting the Flask web tool locally (Python 3.7.2), the following error is given in the console when opening the page:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain".
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Checking the headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

However, on production (when started through Gunicorn) it gives this:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

I am guessing the web-server (Apache) serves them in the production case, but another thing is when testing other pages of this web tool, they all work all and load 
the javascript files correctly (even if their content-type is text/plain). However the difference is, I noticed,
in the type.

This works in my case:

```
<script src="../../static/js/translator/library/materialize.js"></script>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="../../static/js/translator/library/materialize.js"></script>
```

Of course, I tried this for the problematic `javascript` file and received the following error (which means it now loaded):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This, as far as I researched, basically means I need to set the type to `module` (however this makes the browser decline the .js file).

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another trick without needing to change anything in registry:
put this before importing flask:

```py
# fix windows registry stuff
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js')
mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css')
```

Comment: thanks. this worked for me. Before importing anything else, I add the first two lines inside the __init__.py file.

Answer (score 10):

Problem is caused by how flask is guessing content type of each static file.
To do that flask imports [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) and calls `mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(download_name)`

This module creates a database of known mime types from several sources and uses it to return mime type.

Under Linux and MacOS `mimetypes.py` looks inside files:

```py
knownfiles = [
    "/etc/mime.types",
    "/etc/httpd/mime.types",                    # Mac OS X
    "/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types",               # Apache
    "/etc/apache/mime.types",                   # Apache 1
    "/etc/apache2/mime.types",                  # Apache 2
    "/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types",
    "/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types",
    "/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types",     # Apache 1.2
    "/usr/local/etc/mime.types",                # Apache 1.3
    ]
```

But under Windows it looks inside the registry:

```py
with _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, '') as hkcr:
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
        try:
            with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
                # Only check file extensions
                if not subkeyname.startswith("."):
                    continue
                # raises OSError if no 'Content Type' value
                mimetype, datatype = _winreg.QueryValueEx(
                    subkey, 'Content Type')
                if datatype != _winreg.REG_SZ:
                    continue
                self.add_type(mimetype, subkeyname, strict)
```

So to fix the problem of flask thinking that .js file was actually `text/plain` all that's necessary is to open regedit and adjust this registry key to `application/javascript`:

[image: regedit]

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar trouble around a .js export class which contains a vanilla js web component with an integrated template, itself having jinja2 escape sequences.
So, you may not get the same error with the first script statement using `url_for` as I did.

This appears to load as no error is raised by the templating engine...

`<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='interval_table.js') }}"></script>`

... but Firefox console reports error: `Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/interval_table.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/json”).`
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

I thought to get around the json error with the following, but it results in a jinja2 error, could not create endpoint:

`<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('auth/interval_table.js') }}"></script>`

This doesn't look like a CORS issue, and lots of digging has yielded no results. A new question may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `type="module"` you are able to use the `defer` attribute to achieve the same effect.  Ie: The script will not be executed until the page finishes loading.

```
<script defer src="flong.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module,
you just increased my frustration even more sir, circular problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if it helps, but I had a similar problem and it was solved by changing the module js extension from .js to .mjs. I don't think Flask can see the difference, unlike Node.js, without the different extensions.

I know this is an old thread, but I had a similar problem that was solved using the method I mentioned.

I didn't see this before I posted, but my thread is here:
[Flask Server Not Sending JS Module Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584547/flask-server-not-sending-js-module-script)

Answer (score 0):

Harel Ashwal, Thank you so much.  I was unable to load the external CSS file on flask because of a mimetype error, and this bit you shared fixed it for me:

```
# fix windows registry stuff
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js')
mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css')
```