# Flask Server Not Sending JS Module Script

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, flask

I am building a server in Flask that sends my index.html file just fine, but when it requests index.js (which is a module for other js files), the python terminal says it sends index.js, but it doesn't show up on the browser sources.

Server/Browser info:

```
Browser requests index.html
Server receives request for index.html
Server sends index.html
Browser receives index.html
Browser requests index.js
Server receives request for index.js
Server sends index.js
Browser fails to receive index.js
```

However, I have another script for other things that is not a module called functions.js, (Evidently modules cannot have content accessible by the console and various other places) it loads, same with style.css.

HTML Link:

```
<script type="module" src="../static/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/functions.js"></script>
```

[image: This is what the console throws]

What's frustrating is this issue doesn't happen on a server I made on Node.js, but I want to run the server on Flask because of some other reasons I won't disclose. I have previously received the same error on the browser using the Node.js server, but I recognize that was some problem referring to the combination of type="module" or type="text/javascript" and using js as a module/just a script. Using the same index.html and index.js files as I used on the server run by Node.js, it fails to work on Flask.

Edit:
Okay, I think I have the answer, but I'm unsure! Evidently, module js files have the file extension .mjs instead of .js. I don't understand why it worked on the Node.js server and not Flask. Perhaps it's because Node.js can decipher between the two and Flask cannot? I would love more information on this and perhaps other ways to think about this problem!